# What does WeightedStandardDeviation (in the ExtremeOptimization library) actually *do*?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, extreme-optimization

The Extreme Optimization .NET math and statistics library offers a function called `WeightedStandardDeviation`, for which [the documentation states](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/Documentation/Reference/Extreme.Statistics.Stats.WeightedStandardDeviation.aspx):

> Returns the mean of the variable with observations weighted by the specified vector.

This is clearly (erroneously) copied and pasted from [the documentation for the related `WeightedMean` method](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/Documentation/Reference/Extreme.Statistics.Stats.WeightedMean.aspx). No additional details are provided regarding the actual algorithm.

I cannot find any evidence that there is a standard definition for a weighted standard deviation. [This Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/823138/52057) indicates that there are in fact multiple candidate definitions.

---

As a concrete example, I'm seeing a pretty weird answer when I actually try to use the method.

Given the following values and weights:

```
values = [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, ]
weights = [0.00588121386769639, 0.107841991196409, 0.374376106764772, 0.388925647336988, 0.116838473897444, 0.00613656693669066, ]
```

I get:

```
WeightedStandardDeviation(values, weights) == 58926371.6549313
```

This is obviously absurd; no definition of weighted standard deviation should be orders of magnitude greater than the total range encompassed by the sample values.

The Math.SE answer above cites [this paper](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/donald-gatz/weighted-standard-error.pdf), which offers several candidate definitions for a weighted standard deviation. Using the first definition, I calculated a weighted SD of about 0.1285.

I also tried just multiplying each weight by 2^16 and rounding to the nearest integer, and treating these as "counts" for a normal (unweighted) standard deviation calculation. I obtained a value of about 0.878 this way.

So the `WeightedStandardDeviation` method appears to be doing something pretty different from either of these, and, moreover, something completely bizarre and obviously incorrect. Does anyone know what the actual algorithm *is* and/or what it's *supposed* to be?

Comment: Maybe just look what it does with decompiler?

Comment: @Evk I've never tried that before, but I've downloaded the ReSharper decompiler and plan to give that a go this coming week.

Comment: Good, but note that since that assembly is not open source (and actually costs money) - they might have obfuscated their code and it might be not easy to extract meaning from such obfuscated code. But if not - you will easily restore the algorithm in question.

Comment: @Evk Yeah, it was definitely obfuscated enough to prevent me from figuring out where in the code the actual math is done, at least in the time I spent looking at it. I think I'll just avoid the function and code my own weighted standard deviation when necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the ExtremeOptimization support team about this, and received an answer.

### The algorithm

The algorithm comes from [this paper](http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/fanf2/hermes/doc/antiforgery/stats.pdf), which provides a definition of "weighted variance" in section 5. The `WeightedStandardDeviation` function returns the square root of this weighted variance.

### The bug

The behavior I noted above regarding huge output values (and probably `NaN` as well) was due to a bug; from the email I received:

> We found that the calculation for double contains a typo: the central sum of squares is divided by (W-1) instead of W. This would result in extremely large (or infinite) values in your example.

This will be **fixed** in an update that will be released **24 April 2017**.

Comment: Did you ever get this update? Extreme's website doesn't list any updates since Mar 2016 and I haven't been able to get in contact with them.

Comment: @Cameron I was never able to install and test the update, but I did download a version I thought might have the patch. I believe they update the patch-version on the website without updating the release date, but I'm not entirely sure of that.